# Search by name using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

When I try to use search on the simple CRUD web-app I get an error "HTTP Status 404". Could you tell me please where is the mistake?

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser/")
public ModelAndView searchUser(@RequestParam("searchName") String searchName) {
    logger.info("Searching the User. User Names: "+searchName);
    List<User> userList = userService.getAllUsers(searchName);
    return new ModelAndView("userList", "userList", userList);
}
```

Here is JSP file:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Users List</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <%-- <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet"> --%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .myrow-container {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class=".container-fluid">
<div class="container myrow-container">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <div align="left"><b>Users List</b> </div>
                <div align="right"><a href="createUser">Add New User</a></div>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <c:if test="${empty userList}">
                <div>There are no Users</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <form action="addDemoData">
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='add Demo Data'/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${not empty userList}">

                <form action="searchUser">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">Search Users: <input type='text' name='searchName' id='searchName'/> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='Search'/></div>
                    </div>
                </form>


                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead style="background-color: #bce8f1;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Admin</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="emp">
                        <tr>
                            <th><c:out value="${emp.id}"/></th>
                            <th><c:out value="${emp.name}"/></th>
                            <th><c:out value="${emp.age}"/></th>
                            <th><c:out value="${emp.admin}"/></th>
                            <th><c:out value="${emp.createdDate}"/></th>
                            <th><a href="editUser?id=<c:out value='${emp.id}'/>">Edit</a></th>
                            <th><a href="deleteUser?id=<c:out value='${emp.id}'/>">Delete</a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div id="pagination">

                    <c:url value="/list" var="prev">
                        <c:param name="page" value="${page-1}"/>
                    </c:url>
                    <c:if test="${page > 1}">
                        <a href="<c:out value="${prev}" />" class="pn prev">Prev</a>
                    </c:if>

                    <c:forEach begin="1" end="${maxPages}" step="1" varStatus="i">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${page == i.index}">
                                <span>${i.index}</span>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <c:url value="/list" var="url">
                                    <c:param name="page" value="${i.index}"/>
                                </c:url>
                                <a href='<c:out value="${url}" />'>${i.index}</a>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <c:url value="/list" var="next">
                        <c:param name="page" value="${page + 1}"/>
                    </c:url>
                    <c:if test="${page + 1 <= maxPages}">
                        <a href='<c:out value="${next}" />' class="pn next">Next</a>
                    </c:if>
                </div>
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <%-- <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-2.1.3.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
     --%>

</body>
</html>
```

It was deployed by war file.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What URL did you use to search?

Comment: Also how is your Spring MVC app deployed? Is it a war file in a servlet container?  These may add additional base paths to your "/searchUser" subpath.  Also you can remove the trailing slash.

Comment: @shmosel  I add my JSP file

Comment: @GameSalutes It was deployed by war file.